# How to Audit User Logins in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint

I'm trying to track SharePoint adoption in our environment.  Not looking for anything as sophisticated as "how extensively are our users accessing SharePoint" - just "how many distinct users are logging into SharePoint each month.  All users are logging in via Windows Authentication.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for something simple, I think OOTB Usage reporting could do for you. [Click here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262541.aspx) to learn about configuration, and check this blog post for a [detailed explanation](http://blogs.msdn.com/markarend/archive/2008/09/06/moss-usage-reports-explained.aspx) for each report available.